# Would a 2 amp audio amp get damaged by a 10ah battery? (im new to this kind of stuff)

Tags: batteries, amplifier, audio, bluetooth, speakers

Okay so I'm building a portable Bluetooth speaker, and i just blew current amp by running too many volts through (*whoops* i wasn't paying attention when i grabbed the adapter). I know this is a dumb question but would a 10 amp hour battery damage a 2 amp board? I'm new to this kind of stuff and i just want to make sure...

Also, would running a 100w amp through 2 12w speakers damage them?

I know that not having enough power supplied for a speaker is potentially more damaging than too much with stuff like clipping, but i don't really want to blow my current speakers up because they were a gift to me

Comment: "I know that not having enough power supplied for a speaker is potentially more damaging than too much with stuff like clipping"?   What? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: A 10 Ah (ampere-hours) battery would not kill a 2 A (amperes) load.  It will however last, 10Ah/2A = 5h, five hours.

Comment: "Also, would running a 100w amp through 2 12w speakers damage them?"  - At full volume it certainly would, just make sure you never turn up the volume if nothing is playing.  As long as something's playing you'll hear when the speakers start to distort (which is probably some time after your hears start to hurt).

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

You seem to be confusing Amps with Amp-Hours; these two are somewhat related, but really are entirely different units of measurement. Electronic devices will often have a current rating, noted in Amps, and a voltage rating, noted in Volts. The current rating marks the amount of electric current drawn by that device under normal operating conditions. You will need to power that device with a power source that is rated for an equal amount of voltage, as well as an equal or greater amount of current.

Amp-Hours, on the other hand, are a measure of battery capacity. A device rated for 10 Amp-hours can source 10 Amps of electric current continuously for 1 hour before it needs to be replaced or recharged. In the context of your example, the 10 Ah battery will be able to power your 2 A board for 5 hours before it dies.

For your second question:

It would be nice to have more detail about the specific amp and speakers that you are using, but the likely answer is that there will be a potential for damaging your 12 W pair of speakers if you connect them to a 100 W amp. That being said, your amp's 100 W rating specifies the maximum power that may be achieved by that amplifier for a certain impedance load; this means that operating the amp at a low level should allow your speakers to operate without sustaining damage. Just remember that there almost certainly will be a potential for damage to those speakers if you aren't very careful with the gain knob.